RDP Connection from windows to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I am trying to connect through RDP from windows to Ubuntu 24.04, i am using remote desktop windows


Are you using the built in feature of 24.04? If so are you using the Desktop Sharing or the Remote Desktop tab? Are you using your login password or the password generated in these settings? Edit your question and add these information.

Desktop Sharing? How does that work, I didn't think it was possible for two remote sessions to share ie - see the same screen since 16.04.

@user628388 I have seen Gnome Desktop Sharing in Ubuntu since 22.04 LTS (I don't keep track of non-LTS releases). It is certainly there in 24.04. You may want to read the official Ubuntu documentation, I am talking about a local desktop session being shared (and optionally controlled) remotely either by yourself or by someone you trust.

on the tab window of the aws amazon menu connect I dont have the RDP connection tab : I just have EC2 instance connect !!! Session manager !!! SSH Client !!! EC2 serial console . I do not know why I used the (RDP) method but I will try to connect through any of those methods . Thank you in advance.

@ThinLizzy Please edit your question and add all the new information. AWS and other cloud instances typically are server versions of Ubuntu. This means they don't have any Desktop or GUI. This means RDP is not right protocol. You will need to use ssh. We can't answer your question unless you provide more details in your question.

Thank you. I will try to connect through SSh.

xRDP is for remotely logging into an ID on a ubuntu system.
unless you explicitly created the user ID "ubuntu" on your system, this would work about as well as trying the ID "iefbr14".
If in fact, during installation you caused the primary ID of your system to be "ubuntu", that's a different problem - and also one that will fail since about ubuntu 18.04 because the system console is already using the primary ID.
What you need is to create a userID on that system (I think the command is adduser)

I created the user : iefbr14 and a  new password. I tried to enter but I got a black screen.

on the tab window of the  aws amazon menu connect I dont have the RDP connection tab  : I just have                                                                                                     EC2 instance connect !!!  Session manager  !!! SSH Client !!!  EC2 serial console  .                                               I do not know why I used the (RDP)  method but  to connect trhough Windows remote Connection , but if you have a hint how to do under those other  methods?

The only client I've had success using is the Windows connection via RDP - for full screen.  For command line connections I've used both putty and telnet.
